# C# CefSharp как открыть внешнию ссылку

Tags: c#, winforms, form, браузер, cefsharp

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. CefSharp открывает сайт и там есть кнопка и если на неё нажать он откроет новое окно отдельно, как сделать что бы открывался там же

Answer (score 0):

Переопределить виртуальный метод `OnBeforeClose`, тогда будет переходить в том же окне.

```
public virtual void OnBeforeClose(IWebBrowser browser)
{
        // Ничего не делать
}
```